# Number Of Connections Limit For A Web Server

Tags: http, web-applications, request, httprequest

I was wondering how can I find the "number of connections limit" for a web server.
Most of the cases I encountered it is limited to 6 connections (Meaning I can have 6 connections to this webserver working at the same time).
Is there any request I can send over HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more precise ? What kind of server ?  Any ? For which OS ?

If it's an Apache http server, you should have a look in the settings file (should be **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** under Linux). Search for **MaxClients** option.
For example, I use a small apache server at home which can process 300 simultaneous requests (connections).

**EDIT :**
I think you won't be able to get the server specifications. You should try to overload it in order to guess its limits.

Comment: I meant number of connections to a web server at the same time.I've Updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: I don't own the server, I wrote a client program and it should be able to evaluate the server specifications for any web server.

Comment: I think you won't be able to get the server specifications, unless you try to overload it to guess its limits.

Comment: I've tried that, But I was looking for a more precise way. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I want to accept your answer. Please update your answer with "overloading and guess" that you said in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like this in the HTTP standard, it aims to isolate HTTP requests from each other as much as possible. There might be a server-specific way to query this.

Depending on the architecture of your server, there could be a far greater number of TCP connections accepted than worker threads generating the HTTP responses, so you need to ask yourself what exactly you are interested in, and then just measure it with jmeter.